# RxJava : combining multiple streams of objects based on a certain condition

Tags: java, rx-java

I have multiple sources of notifications : A, B, C  (all of them producing the different type of objects but having some common properties) that I want to combine into a new Stream when a certain condition is fulfilled.

Example of Streams :

```
A: [ ObjectA(id=1), ObjectA(id=2), ObjectA(id=3), ObjectA(id=5), ObjectA(id=4)]
B: [ ObjectB(id=1), ObjectB(id=2), ObjectB(id=3), ObjectB(id=4), ObjectB(id=5)]
C: [ ObjectC(id=1), ObjectC(id=2), ObjectC(id=3), ObjectC(id=4), ObjectC(id=5)]
```

The desired output:

```
Result: [ ObjectABC(id=1), ObjectABC(id=2), ObjectABC(id=3), ObjectA(id=4), ObjectA(id=5)]
```

Each `ObjectABC` will be created and added to the result stream when an `ObjectA`, `ObjectB` and `ObjectC` having the same id are received.

If no match found it should wait until a triplet having the same I'd is found.

In the examples when the current triplet items received does not match (like for the fourth iteration A's fourth item has an Id = 5 ) it should be kept until a the matching items from the other streams are processed or discarded after a period of time.

Is this can be achievable via RxJava.

Comment: If there is a match, you want to combine all three. But if ids don't match at a point of time, what should happen to those three items?

Comment: @Arnav I have added detail about that

Comment: So for every set of values, if all ids are the same pass on the result stream and discard the rest? So, in the desired output you can't accept the 4th and 5th values right?

Comment: @ArnavRao updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an IDE to hand, but this should explain the logic:

```
// First, extract all of the IDs as they arrive
final Observable<Integer> ids = as.map(i -> i.id).distinct();

// Then, for each ID, extract the ObjectA, ObjectB and ObjectC instances
// and zip them together. 
final Observable<ObjectABC> abcs = ids.flatMap(id -> Observable.zip(
    as.filter(a -> a.id.equals(id)).take(1), 
    bs.filter(b -> b.id.equals(id)).take(1), 
    cs.filter(c -> c.id.equals(id)).take(1),
    (a, b, c) -> new ObjectABC(a, b, c));
```

If you want to enforce ordering:

```
abcs.sort(Comparator.comparing(abc -> abc.id));
```